# Converting a String object into an array using whitespace as separators [Java]

Tags: java, converters

I'm trying to create a program in Java that takes user input and converts it into Pig Latin. To do this, I am planning to get the user input, store it as a String, and somehow convert it to an array so I am able to work with each individual word in there.

How should I go about this?

Comment: One would start by reviewing the spec for [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: I would recommend looking into the java Scanner class and showing attempted code BEFORE posting to stackoverflow. Also your tags do not match the question.

Answer (score 0):

I like Commons Lang StringUtils, which has [a split method with various options](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). The default splits by whitespace.

```
 String[] parts = StringUtils.split(theString);
```

Answer (score 0):

[split();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

```
try {
    String[] splitArray = yourString.split("\\s+");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {

}
```

I would recommend You check the Java docs, as there are many ways of doing that. (i.e StringTokenizer)

Comment: Does that work for consecutive spaces? Or newlines? or tabs? Or Unicode whitespace?

Comment: You can use "\\s" is a Regex for whitespace, look @ edited answer